# Time stamp vba simplification

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone could help me compress or simplify this Vba code.

I want to include columns A-J without having to duplicate the code for each column.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 10).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 11).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 9).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 10).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 8).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 9).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3:E9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 6).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 6).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3:F9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 5).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 5).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H3:H9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I3:I9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J3:J9999")) Is Nothing Then
       
        
        For Each cell In Target
       
                If cell.Value = "" Then
               
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
       
            Else
               
                If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                End If
                    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
       
            End If
              
        Next cell
   
    End If
 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail when this code should run? Will you be writing to one cell or copy/pasting to a row, a column, or even a range of data? The more cells you copy/paste, the slower the code gets. Restricting it to one cell may be a good idea. Also, there is a hardly noticeable difference in the code for columns `A:C` and the code for columns `D:J`. Please do clarify.

Comment: The code would run when an edit is made in the row in cells A:J and a time stamp would appear an “K” and an edited time in “L” and both “K” and “L” would disappear when the data is deleted. 

I had it restricted to one cell but other cells might be edited. 

The code is just duplicated so it would run each time a cell is edited for A:J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change

- You need to consider two important characteristics of this event:

  1. You need to prevent re-triggering it when writing to cells by setting `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` but not to forget to set it to `True` after writing has finished.
  2. If an error occurs, `Application.EnableEvents` might remain `False`, which would prevent any event from triggering. Therefore, using an error-handling routine, you need to make sure it gets set to `True` before exiting the procedure.
- This example is restricted to one cell only. If you copy-paste more than one cell, no changes will be made.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' enable error handling

    Const fRow As Long = 3
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' restrict to one cell
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    With Columns("A:J")
        '  'A3:J1048576'
        Set crg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1)
        Set iCell = Intersect(crg, Target)
    End With
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' if many cells
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not retrigger when writing
    
    If IsEmpty(iCell) Then
        iCell.EntireRow.Columns("K:L").ClearContents
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Cells(iCell.Row, "K")) Then
            Cells(iCell.Row, "K").Value = Now
        End If
        Cells(iCell.Row, "L").Value = Now
    End If

SafeExit:

    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then ' re-enable events (even if error)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' if many cells 
    
    Exit Sub
    
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, i As Long

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A3:J9999")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("A3:J9999"))
           i = 11 - Target.Column
           If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, i).ClearContents
                cell.Offset(0, i + 1).ClearContents
           Else
               If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                   cell.Offset(0, i).Value = Now
               End If
               cell.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Now
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate it, it works perfectly!